# How to optimally download a list of files from s3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a java application that works with files stored in a s3 bucket. At times I need to download multiple files for my application to do work. Currently I have a simple for loop for this job as bellow:

```
private List<JSONObject> getFilesFromS3(List<String> filenames) throws IOException {
    List<JSONObject> output = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String item : filenames) {
        S3Object s3Object = s3Service.getFile(item);
        S3ObjectInputStream is = s3Object.getObjectContent();
        String str = new String(is.readAllBytes());
        output.add(XML.toJSONObject(str));
    }
    return output;
}
```

As you can imagine for a few files it is manageable. But for 10,20,30 files that would make an app rather slow. I wonder if there is some s3 lib or method that can speed this up?

I found [TransferManager](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-transfermanager.html) which almost does what I need - unfortunately it only offers to download the entire directory, which is not an option seeing as my s3 bucket has ~50k files. Downloading 50k files to find specific 10 seems not worth it.

So what else can I try? I have encountered methods like `.listobjects()` before but they all would require some sort of a loop so I assume they can't help me here.

Is there something else that I missed, or simply what I want cannot be done/ has not been invented yet? I effectively would like something that would produce a list of S3Objects (which as you can see I would then make into a list of JSONObject items)

Comment: In case there is no out-of-the-box API from AWS S3, one option would always be to use multi threading in Java to download files. Example with `parallelStream`.

Comment: @BojanTrajkovski I was hoping to avoid streams as my application already has a lot of threads & streams, but it seems like it is the only way forward. happy to accept your answer for now. Couldn't finding anything myself

Comment: Update: if you are using Spring framework, I would advise using @Async instead as parallelStream have certain drawbacks and was a bit of a nightmare to deal with for me. A good guide on how to implement this can be found here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/. The custom executor is nice but you may want to check out this resource to see if you need one: https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor-Configuration-with-Spring-Boot/

Comment: Additionally you can use reactive programming (but that may be a bit overkill and probably would require to change your app a bit if you already have a set up). Subject to your use case. A great set of videos about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IK26KdGRl48&list=PLnXn1AViWyL70R5GuXt_nIDZytYBnvBdd&index=1